# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working, button only displays

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, path

I've seen a couple topics for this, but I am still unable to get it working.  The button for the dropdown appears correctly but when I click it to show the list of dropdowns, it directs me to "This page can't be displayed".

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Responsive Design Tutorial | RevillWeb.com</title>

    <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- BODY PAGE CONTENT -->
<div class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li> Apple </li>
        <li> Banana </li>
        <li> Cherry </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Include jQuery and bootstrap JS plugins -->
<script src="includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I fixed this by changing:

```
<script src="includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but I wanted to use the static paths instead of the sources located online.  Also I checked that the paths were correct as I able to do another bootstrap tutorial with the same paths.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of your *local* `jQuery` is  **2.1.0**.  The version your are getting from the Google site is **1.11.1**.

Download the latest `1.11.x` version and use it locally.  This will make your setup the same as the one you successfully tested.

The rest is **FYI**

From [`jQuery` site](http://jquery.com/download/) (with my emphasis):

jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but **does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8**.

Since IE 8 is still relatively common, **we recommend using the 1.x version** unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8 users are visiting the site.

For other details see [jQuery 1.11 and 2.1 Released](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/)

Comment: thanks for your reply! I downloaded the 1.11.x version for jQuery and the dropdown menu works but only in chrome.  When I opened the same file locally on IE the same error occurred ("This page can't be displayed).  My version is 11.0.x for IE.

Comment: This is strange since both [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) and [`Bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support) should support `IE11`.

Comment: IE was blocking any scripts so I changed that setting and it works, thanks for all your help :)